# Deploy firebase functions / ui as part of bazel build

Tags: firebase, bazel

Is there a way to deploy firebase functions or firebase hosting as part of a Bazel build?

Comment: Did you find out a solution ?

Comment: No, I imagine it can be done with an sh_binary rule or rules_nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same question, thankfully I found the answer.
You can achieve this with `nodejs_binary`.

Assuming that your WORKSPACE is correctly setup (you are using `npm_install` in the WORKSPACE file), use the following rule in you BUILD file.

```
# Load what you need
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:index.bzl", "nodejs_binary")

nodejs_binary(
    name = "deploy",
    chdir = package_name(),
    data = [
        # Add your dependencies here
    ],
    # Remember to install firebase-tools
    entry_point = "@npm//:node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js",
    templated_args = [
        "--project",
        "<YOUR PROJECT ID>",
        "--config",
        "$$(rlocation <PATH TO YOUR firebase.json CONFIG>)",
        "deploy",
    ],
```

With the above setup just call

```bash
bazel run //path/to/your/module:deploy
```

and you are good to go.

Just remember to sign in to firebase with `firebase auth`, because by default the firebase-tools will use your authentication setup.